# Sort Date (Newest to Oldest) ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

this is index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to_modal_new(new_master_film_path, "Enter film") %>
<%= link_to_export("Master films", params) %>

<%=  paginate @master_films %>

<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Serial</th>
      <th>Formula</th>
      <th>Mix/g</th>
      <th>Mach</th>
      <th>ITO top</th>
      <th>Thinky</th>
      <th>Chemist</th>
      <th>Operator</th>
      <th>Inspector</th>
      <th>Eff W</th>
      <th>Eff L</th>
      <th>Yield</th>
      <th>Defects</th>
      <th>Laminated</th>
      <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>     
    <%= render @master_films %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to organize the Date column in desc (newest to oldest) dates. I added the following dropdown option but it fails. Error template. Or if I can default the sort to newest Laminated date is first.

```
 <%= render 'shared/sort_dropdown', current: sort, choices: [['serial','desc'], ['laminated','desc']] %>
```

Comment: This question is really unclear. Do you want to order the records in the DB? In that case you would do `MyModel.order(column_name: 'desc')`. What are your models? What is an example of the data and what is the expected output? What exactly went wrong? "but it fails" is useless information.

Comment: master_film.order(laminated: 'desc') <- so I could do this?

Comment: @Stephanie do you want to sort by `laminated` column? Does it contain the date you mentioned in question title? If yes then, yes :-) BUT you should do that in the controller, not in view. That is not a good practice in rails (high cost). I have updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this in detail, assuming you are very new to rails because of the way you asked the question and the way your code of view is. My apologies, if I am wrong.

In your controller (I guess it should be `films_controller.rb` or `master_films_controller.rb`), the action in which you are calculating this `@master_films` (it will have same name as the view that has the code you posted in question), add this:

```
  @master_films = MasterFilm.all.order('laminated DESC')
  # OR
  @master_films = MasterFilm.all.order(laminated: 'desc')
  # letter case does not matter
```

Your table code in view is not correct. It should be:

```
  <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Serial</th>
      <th>Formula</th>
      <th>Mix/g</th>
      <th>Mach</th>
      <th>ITO top</th>
      <th>Thinky</th>
      <th>Chemist</th>
      <th>Operator</th>
      <th>Inspector</th>
      <th>Eff W</th>
      <th>Eff L</th>
      <th>Yield</th>
      <th>Defects</th>
      <th>Laminated</th>
      <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= @master_films.each do |master_film| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= master_film.serial %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.formula %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.mix %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.mach %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.ito_top %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.thinky %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.chemist %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.operator %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.inspector %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.eff_w %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.eff_l %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.yield %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.defects %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.laminated %></td>
        <td><%= master_film.note %></td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank ARK, yes my code is correct, the issue is that when the data is pulled from the database, it shows the oldest first. Is the code addition you added after the <%= @master_films.each is this for the new Rails update. in my _master_film.html.erb has the following

Comment: ```<tr id="<%= "masterfilm-#{master_film.id}" %>">
  <td>
    <%= link_to_modal_edit(edit_master_film_path(master_film), master_film, class: "edit-master-film") %>
  </td>
  <td class="serial"><%= master_film.serial %></td>
  <td class="formula"><%= master_film.formula %></td>
 ```

Comment: `[array].each` simply helps to loop through an array of any length. It's just an easy way to loop.

Comment: I am not sure but I guess you are somewhat confused about HTML tables. I hope this will help you: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp If you still need help, mention me again.